# how to make a child width same as parent (center widget inside datacolumn)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use `Expanded` in a `DataColumn` but I got `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`

The idea is, I want to make the text inside the column center.
So I code like below:

```
    DataColumn(
      label: Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Center',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

The only way I can make it is by using `Expanded`. But it will make me a `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`

So, other than `Expanded`, how can I make my child widget has the size same as the parent widget, in my case, the `DataColumn` widget?

Thanks

PS. full code of my `DataTable`

```
  Widget getDataTable() {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const [
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'center 1',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'center 2',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const [
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Expanded(
                child: Center(child: Text('centered content')),
              ),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Expanded(
                child: Center(child: Text('centered content 2')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: `Expanded` will be used only on `Row` or `Column`.

Comment: Yeah. I know. So my question is how to achieve the centering in DataColumn. or how to make child widget the same size of parent widget.

Comment: Are you using `PaginatedDataTable`?. Is it intended to use that? Can you add your full code

Comment: I am just using `DataTable`. will update my code. But I think just the `DataColumn` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter code snippet, the code you write as is no issue and work well. There may another error? Here is I test and copy from flutter code snippet with `DataColumn()`.

```
      DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                color:Colors.red,
                child: const Text(
                  'Name',
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Actually the code can be run. but there will be `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget` in debug console. And after I removed the `Expanded` code, the error is gone. And in flutter, `Expanded` will be used only on `Row` or `Column`. So I think this is why the error occurs

Comment: No. your main problem is in `DataRow()` , adding `Expanded()` and `Center()` together. Check again. Remove `Expanded()` and `Center()` from `DataCell()`. I already test in my project. There is no issue in `DataColum()` with `Expanded()` widget.

Comment: But then why `DataCell` cant accept `Expanded` instead?

Comment: I suppose, `DataCell()` is makeup with `SizedBox()`. Check in `DataCell()` build in code. `Expanded()` is work only with *Row*, *Column* and some other widget. So It can't be compatible. That is only my option. If some better solution pease tell me :3

Answer (score 1):

`DataCell()` is made of `SizedBox.shrink()`:

`SizedBox.shrink()` : It creates a box that will become as small as its parent allows.

`Expanded()` : It tries to occupy all the space available

So, that's the reason you are getting error of,

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Avoid wrapping `DataCell` with `Expanded`:

```
DataRow(
                cells: [
                  DataCell(
                    Text('centered content 1'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('centered content 2'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```